# FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT vs onSaveInstance()

Tags: android, stack, android-activity, bundle, flags

I need to save the `state` of an `Activity`. It is a `treeview`, I `draw` it and as it takes a while I'd like not to start a new `Activity` every time I go to visit this `page` but using the already drawn page.

I solved my issue calling the `Activity` every time with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`. I tried for hours to use `onSaveInstance()` to fill a `bundle` to be reused every time `onCreate()` is called but unfortunately I didn't figure out why the `method` was not called.

So my question is, why should I go crazy saving the `state` of my `Activity` in a `bundle`, knowing that `onSaveInstance` is not part of the app `lifecycle`, while I could simply "look for" my old `activity` in the `stack` and bring it it the `front` easily?